# UISearchBar width and position changes upon selection

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm having a really frustrating problem that I'm sure has a simple solution but for the life of me, I can't figure it out.

I have a UITableView within a UIViewController. On the toolbar, I have a button that can show/hide a Search Bar. Everything works great except for the annoying fact that the search bar, upon selection, shifts up 8 pixels (the original margin between the UITableView and the SuperView) and expands in width to equal the full superview.

[image: showSearchController()]
[image: Selected]

I have kind of fixed the width issue with the function searchBarFrame(), however, it cuts the "Cancel" button in half, so it isn't perfect (See Below). I'd really appreciate any thoughts on these two problems. I have tried every combination of Extend Edges and Scroll View Insets based on other solutions I've found, but nothing is working for me. I really don't want to use the navigation bar as the search bar nor do I want to convert completely to a UITableViewController. There must be a way to make this work!

[image: Width Fixed?]

Here is my (relevant?) code:

```
class ListVC: UIViewController UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBtn: UIBarButtonItem!

let searchController: UISearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
}

func searchBarFrame() {
    var searchBarFrame = searchController.searchBar.frame
    searchBarFrame.size.width = tableView.frame.size.width
    searchController.searchBar.frame = searchBarFrame
}

func showSearchController() {
    searchController.isActive = true
    searchBarFrame()

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true

    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Places"
    searchController.searchBar.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 5.0)
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blurColor

    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}

func hideSearchController() {
    tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
    searchController.isActive = false
}

@IBAction func onSearchBtnPress(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if !searchController.isActive {
        showSearchController()
    } else {
        hideSearchController()
    }
}
```

Comment: In searchBarFrame(), try to print "tableView.frame.size.width" and check whether that is printing the expected width

Comment: and how did you set the tableview frame?

Comment: @vincent-joy I set the views using autolayout in the storyboard. I printed both frames in updateSearchResults using:

`print("Searchbar frame: \(self.view.convert(searchController.searchBar.frame, to: searchController.searchBar.superview))")
print("Tableview frame: \(tableView.frame)")`

These are the results: 
Searchbar frame: (-20.0, 0.0, 414.0, 56.0)
Tableview frame: (20.0, 8.0, 374.0, 612.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up, in case anyone else experienced this issue. After a lot of time and effort, I never got my original setup to work. Instead, I started from scratch and approached it differently.

In storyboard (you can do this programmatically too but I went the easier route because I was fed up), I put a UISearchBar inside a UIView inside a UIStackView. I set the Stackview's leading and trailing constraints to the uitableview, the bottom to the top of the uitableview and the top to the bottom of the top layout view. The UIView's only constraint is a height of 56 (the typical search bar height) with a priority of 999 (if you want to show and hide).

This fixed everything and the code was really simple too.

```
class MyVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchView.isHidden = true
    }

    @IBAction func onSearchBtnPress(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if searchView.isHidden {
            searchView.isHidden = false
        } else {
            searchView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}

extension MyVC: UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that the use of `NSLayoutConstraint` to position and size your views would solve this issue.

For example:

```
private let margin: CGFloat = 15.0

tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: margin),
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: margin),
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
    searchBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.widthAnchor)
])
```

Comment: Sounds like this might help although I don't need to adjust the tableview position, just the searchbar (searchcontroller.view). But where would I put this code? It keeps crashing on me.